# How to create a top level xelement with multiple xelement nodes in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am looking to create a top level XElement with multiple XElement child nodes as below.

```
<Names>
    <Name>
        <firstname>Mike</firstname>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <firstname>Sam</firstname>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <firstname>Michelle</firstname>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    </Name>
</Names>
```

If I go with something similar to below, how can I append the child elements ( elements) to  a top level element  ? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var str = GetName(i);
    //str is a string that contains xml
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
    XElement nameEle = doc.Root;

}
```

Comment: your input is not really clear: what is the `Getelement` method? What are you wanting for output? XDocument, with the depicted structure?

Comment: which `Name` should root contain? there are three in your example

Comment: @NicolasR, I think my naming convention was confusing. I changed it to GetName() which will return one instance of <Name> element in string format. Then I convert that string to an XElement. I want to put this XElement <Name> under a root node <Names>. I am looking for output as XElement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse string for each `<Name>` as `XElement` instead of `XDocument`, for example :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<Names></Names>");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var str = GetName(i);
    var name = XElement.Parse(str);
    doc.Root.Add(name);
}
```

or more fancy (but less readable?) using LINQ :

```
doc.Root
   .Add(
        Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                  .Select(i => XElement.Parse(GetName(i)))
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

I interpret your question as how to use LINQ to XML (`XDocument`, `XElement` etc.) to create XML elements from some data. LINQ to XML was built to support what is called [functional construction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387019.aspx) which allows you to create an XML tree in a single statement. In my oppinion this is the best way to create XML elements as opposed to mutating an existing structure.

To create the XML elements you need some data and this data should be in the form of an `IEnumerable<T>` sequence (the basic interface of LINQ). My little sample uses an array of anonymous types:

```
var names = new[] {
  new { FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Smith" },
  new { FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Smith" },
  new { FirstName = "Michelle", LastName = "Smith" }
};
```

You can also create the `IEnumerable<T>` sequence using a call to a function:

```
var names = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => GetName(i));
```

This assumes that `GetName(i)` will return an object that has a `FirstName` and a `LastName` property.

You can then create the XML elements in a single statement using functional construction:

```
var xElement = new XElement("Names",
  names.Select(
    name => new XElement("Name",
      new XElement("FirstName", name.FirstName),
      new XElement("LastName", name.LastName)
    )
  )
);
```

The structure and indentation of the code mirrors the resulting XML and makes it easy to understand what is going on:

```
<Names>
  <Name>
    <FirstName>Mike</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Name>
  <Name>
    <FirstName>Sam</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Name>
  <Name>
    <FirstName>Michelle</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Name>
</Names>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just read some documentation like on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx

And then it really helps to scroll to the bottom, where there is an example.

In practice, you new up some new XElements, and add them to other elements, that do not necessarily have to be the root element.